# how I can run cypress script with the variable provided by user

Tags: cypress

I have cypress script that runs on different environment and the spec files look like this

````
describe('Whitelabel Login', () => {
  it('Whitelabel Login', () => {
    const whitelabelBaseUrl = whitelabelUrl =>
      whitelabelUrl.replace('://', '://motivaction.')

    cy.visit(whitelabelBaseUrl(Cypress.config('whitelabelUrl')))
    cy.screenshot('Whitelbel Login page', { capture: 'fullPage' })
    cy.visit(`${whitelabelBaseUrl(Cypress.config('whitelabelUrl'))}/logout`)
    cy.screenshot('Whitelbel Logout page', { capture: 'fullPage' })
  })
})```
So when I am running the script npx cypress run --env name=qa wl=seedling

then I want `motivaction` to be replaces by seedling is there any way that I can achieve it
````

Comment: you have to use a comma to separate env variables, not a space:
`npx cypress run --env name=qa,wl=seedling`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference variables passed in through the `--env` flag in the CLI via `Cypress.env('var-name')`. [Cypress documentation here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-4-env)

```
const whitelabelBaseUrl = whitelabelUrl.replace('://', `://${Cypress.env('wl')}.`)
```

Also, pass several env variables using commas and no space. See docs [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run-env-lt-env-gt)

```
npx cypress run --env name=qa,wl=seedling
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and it worked

Comment: @RitaBasu-ghosh would you mind selecting this answer as the correct one? It helps for visibility with future problems.